# How to solve second order DE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The problem is $$y''y'=1,  \ y(0)=1,  \ y'(0)=1$$

This is what I know, in general form a second order DE is given by,

$$y''+ay'+by=0, a,b \ \text{constants}.$$

Solutions are given by $y_1=C_1e^x$ and $y_2=C_2e^{-x}$.

So we rewrite our DE and get the following $y'-\frac{1}{'y}=0$. Now let $y=e^{rx},$ for some real number $r$. Then $y'=re^{rx}$ and $y''=r^2e^{rx}$. We then get, $$r^2e^{rx}-a\frac{1}{re^{rx}}=0.$$

Now here is where my problem lies, usually you can factor out $(r^2-ar)e^{rx}$ and solve $(r^2-ar)=0$. Bur since I can't do it in this case because $e^{rx}$ is both in the nominator and denominator I do not now how to proceed with solving this DE. Have very little experience with DE's in generall and trying to follow my notes, so a bit of guidance would be highly appreciated,

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another technique would be letting $y'=\frac{dy}{dx}=v$. Then, $y''=\frac{dv}{dx}=v'$ and

$$v'v=1 \implies v\,dv=dx \implies \frac{v^2}{2}=x+c_1\implies v^2=2x+c_1$$

from which you can substitute $y'=v$ to form

$$(y')^2=2x+c_1\implies \frac{dy}{dx}=\sqrt{2x+c_1}\implies dy=\sqrt{2x+c_1}\,dx$$

whereby integrating both sides forms

$$y=\frac{1}{3}\left(2x+c_1\right)^{3/2}+c_2$$

therefore

$$y'=\sqrt{2x+c_1}$$

from which you can find the solution through the initial conditions.

Comment: This was very easy to follow and great explanation, thank you for taking your time to provide this!

Comment: I was told today that = that this is not true, due to doing to separate operations on each sides, just for your notice! Very much appreciate the effort!

Comment: @MisterButter: The substitution matches the answer provided by [Mathematica](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%E2%80%B2%E2%80%B2y%E2%80%B2%3D1). I'm not sure what is wrong with that substitution - the independent variable is $x$?

Comment: I see, the motivation I got from our TA is that since $dy$ is not equivalent to $dx$, so $v\,dv\ne dx$

Comment: The tips I got to solve this was to solve $yy'=1$ instead and treat it as a separable differential equation.

Comment: That is exactly what the substitution is doing - it is lowering the degree of the equation by one and then treating the equation as a first order equation which is separable. I'm not sure why your TA marked this technique incorrect - perhaps another user on this site can give feedback.

Comment: Yeah, I don't see any problem with this method. The only problem I have is that the answer I get, seems to somehow be wrong since I get the message "The domain of your function doesn't match that of the correct answer", and my answer is $\frac{1}{3}(2x+1)^{3/2}+\frac{2}{3}$

Answer (score 2):

> in general form a second order DE is given by
>   $y''+ay'+by=0, a,b \ \text{constants}.$

Certainly not. However, to solve your differential equation, you should notice that $y''y'$ is the derivative of  $\dfrac{1}{2}y^{\prime 2}$...

Comment: just to clarify, you say that $y''y'=$ the derivative of a half y prim to the power of two right?, Thank you for your input and time!

Comment: yes, sorry for the misprint. I'm editing right away.

Comment: Thank you! Since I'm not getting any wiser here, could you perhaps point me to what the above DE is called? Since it isn't a general second order DE.

Comment: It **is** a second order DE. What you call a general second DE is called a linear DE with constant coefficients. A general DE is an equation of the form $F(y,y',...,y^{(n)})=0$.

Comment: That explains it, thank you for pointing it out!